# MySQL sql_mode Turning Strict Mode Off Permanently Linux for WHMCS

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu, whmcs

I'm not super experienced at this but I've been trying to get the mySQL `strict_mode` setting to be enforced permanently so that I can install and set up the database to install WHMCS.

Problem is I have seen many different posts and people saying you should alter the my.cnf file and put in the following sql_mode setting:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode="TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
```

I've also tried just the following:

```
sql_mode= "TRADITIONAL"
```

There doesn't seem to be any effect from these. When I restart mySQL and then check the mode using this:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

I get the following which apparently means I'm still in strict mode:

> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   | @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                                                                                    |
>   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
>   +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I can however set the strict mode temporarily off for the session using this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode ="";
```

The problem is that setting won't hold when the machine is restarted and then it reverts back to strict mode.

Does anyone have some more definitive suggestion on how I can get strict mode permanently off in MySQL on ubuntu to allow me to use WHMCS?

I can't seem to find any other config files that may be overriding this strict mode setting, but I could be missing something that is.

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `sql-mode` (with a dash) in the config file?

Comment: Also, did you check that there's no other file included that overrides this setting? (eg. files in `/etc/mysql/conf.d`)

Comment: Hi fejese. In Linux I was under the impression it's supposed to be sql_mode unless I'm mistaken. I think it's dash "-" with Windows. Under my folder /etc/mysql/conf.d/ there is one file called  mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf    inside it is only 2 lines: [mysqld_safe]syslog

Answer (score 1):

There are two files initially followed by mysql after restarting.
You can look for "sql_mode" in these following files and update them as per your requirements: `/etc/my.cnf` or `/usr/my.cnf`

You have to do it as a root user and then it will never change after mysql restart again.